# Don't have access to data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have some row in a table, I would like to have only a form for all the web page instead having one for every one.
Every row can be edited or delete.
I tried to use data attribute to share use it to do a generic action.

html

```
<div id="deleteConfirm" title="Delete user?" style="display:none">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>..Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<button type="button" id="deleteButton1" data-userName="test1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteButton2" data-userName="test2" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
</button>
```

js

```
$("[id^=deleteButton]").button({
icons: {
    primary: "ui-icon-minus"
},
text: false
});

$("[id^=deleteButton]").click(function () {
//var userName = $("[id^=deleteButton]").data('data-reportname');
var userName = $(this).data('userName');
alert(userName);
$("#deleteConfirm").data('userName', userName).dialog("open")
  //  $("#deleteConfirm").dialog("open");
});

$("#deleteConfirm").dialog({
autoOpen: false,
resizable: false,
width: 400,
height: 180,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    "Delete user": function () {
    alert($(this).data('userName'));
    $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    Cancel: function () {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
});
```

I can't read data attribute.

I create a basic test 
http://jsfiddle.net/q5fLz/1/

Answer (score 4):

The `data` attributes must be all lowercase:

```
<button type="button" id="deleteButton1" data-username="test1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteButton2" data-username="test2" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
</button>
```

```
$("[id^=deleteButton]").click(function () {
    var userName = $(this).data('username');
    alert(userName);
    $("#deleteConfirm").data('username', userName).dialog("open")
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5fLz/2/)

Note that because jQuery places all data attributes into an object, it converts attribute names with hyphens to camel case. Eg. `user-name` can be accessed using `$.data('user-name')` or `$.data('userName')`. Your use of camelcase within the HTML attribute confused jQuery to thinking the property was `data-user-name`.

Comment: For those curious people, like me, who were wondering where in the spec it said `data-*` attributes had to be all lower-case, [here's a link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Answer (score 2):

Data attributes should be defined as **dash-delimited** (`user-name`), and you read them in jQuery as **camel-case normalized** (`userName`).

Quote from [source](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes) (thanks to @ajp15243):

> **element**.dataset Returns a `DOMStringMap` object for the element's
>   `data-*` attributes.
>
> Hyphenated names become camel-cased. For example, `data-foo-bar=""`
>   becomes `element.dataset.fooBar`.

So, this change to DOM should work with your jQuery code:

```
<div id="deleteConfirm" title="Delete user?" style="display:none">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>..Are you sure?</p>
    </div>

<button type="button" id="deleteButton1" data-user-name="test1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
</button>
<button type="button" id="deleteButton2" data-user-name="test2" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span>
</button>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Ap2ZH/